# Asynchronous ajax call and async c# controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, extjs

The scenario is as follow.

I have an ajax request call in extjs. By default its async is true, which means that ajax call will be Asynchronous. On the server side, I also have a method with a return type of Task, which means its also an Async.
What will be the difference between making an Ajax call and Server side method both async? When is the need of making controller async with task?

Extjs ajax example:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/api/students',
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 60000,
        params:
        {
            id: 1 // loads student whose Id is 1
        },
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function (response) {

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Request Failed.');

        }
    });
```

Controller class example:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> students()
  {
    return Ok()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side doing async will allow the UI to stay responsive, since JavaScript is single threaded it's not blocking the UI when it's calling the server.

On the server side doing async allows the server to handle more requests, as your controller calls an async operation of a backend service it's freed up to handle another incoming request in the meantime.

Typically, the server side controller becomes async by calling a service/repo it depends on that is also async.  A few years ago I saw a demo given by Scott Hanselman in which he did a comparison that using async in server code does yield better perf as supposed to non async code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its recommended to use async requests on client side since it doesn't block UI.

Comment: So its best prectice you mean, to use async on both client and server side for better performance?

Comment: @TwinkleB. Yeah, on the client side you are pretty much doing it anyway, on the server side you sometimes have a choice and I would use async whenever I can.